# Multiple Websites & Invoices Numbers - Database Design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-connection

I'm currently having few websites on one dedicated server however I need to move two of them to separate servers.

I have a table that is storing invoices for services that are serving on these websites.

Does anybody has any idea how to solve invoices issue?

In my country, I need to keep numbering order correct so I suppose that I need to keep invoices from all websites in one table. But how as I'll have few database servers, totally separated.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any issue. The one and only database is still central right?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat - there are few databases.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you move the application to another server doesn't mean you need to move the database to another server.  All modern databases support remote/networked access, so you can keep the database where it is and have the applications continue to talk to it.  The only thing that should require changing is your database configuration/connection string.

I'm unsure what sort of application stack you're using, but [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html) link provides details on how to enable remote access to a MySQL database if it's disabled (for some reason).  By default, I believe it should work.

Comment: I thought about putting invoices table on small separate MySQL server. Any suggestions about approach?